# Oracle Privileges to Use Global Temporary Table via Definer's Rights Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, privileges, sql-grant, global-temp-tables

Please assume:

User `A` creates global temporary table `gtt`.

User `A` creates stored procedure `sp` with definer's rights `AUTHID DEFINER`.  For simplicity, assume this `sp` simply inserts a row into `gtt` and selects a value from the row in `gtt`.

User `A` grants user `B` `execute` on `sp`.

What additional grants, if any, need to be given to users `A` and `B` so that `B` can successfully execute `sp`?

I've heard that when a global temporary table is used (e.g. data inserted), that the user using the global temporary table needs `create table` privilege to create the instance of the globaly temporary table in their session's memory (even though the global temporary table itself was already created).  Is that true?  I assumed granting select and insert on the global temporary table would have been sufficient.

Because `sp` is defined by `A` does this mean `A` needs `create any table`, so the row of data can be inserted and selected from user `B`'s session memory?

Sorry, I don't currently have access to an Oracle instance where I have enough privileges to try this myself.

Please note, I am *not* trying to create the global temporary table in the stored procedure.

Using Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition.

Thank you in advance for helping me understand the privileges involved here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What additional grants, if any, need to be given to users A and B so that B can successfully execute sp?

None.

---

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create global temporary table gtt (name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure sp
  2    authid definer
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    insert into gtt (name) values (user);
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec sp;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from gtt;

NAME
--------------------
SCOTT

SQL> grant execute on sp to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Everything works so far for the `GTT` and `SP` owner. Let's see the grantee.

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> exec scott.sp;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From scott.gtt;
select * From scott.gtt
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Right; as I said, no other privileges are needed - stored procedure works (i.e. didn't fail), but - as `scott` didn't grant any additional privileges, `mike` can't check `gtt` table's contents.

Back to `scott`:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> select * From scott.gtt;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

But of course; that's a global temporary table - `scott` sees only its own data (which is now lost).

---

**[EDIT: to answer questions you posted as comments]**

`mike` had `create table` privilege; now it doesn't:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> revoke create table from mike;

Revoke succeeded.
```

This piece of code is a copy/paste from above:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create global temporary table gtt (name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure sp
  2    authid definer
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    insert into gtt (name) values (user);
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec sp;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from gtt;

NAME
--------------------
SCOTT

SQL> grant execute on sp to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Additionally, `scott` now grants `select` on `gtt` to `mike`:

```
SQL> grant select on gtt to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

What does `mike` see now?

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> exec scott.sp;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from scott.gtt;

NAME
--------------------
MIKE

SQL>
```

Comment: @ Littlefoot.  Thank you for putting this demo together and sharing the results.
What if, from ``scott`` you had additionally ``grant select on gtt to mike``, would ``mike`` be able to see his row inserted via ``sp``?  If so, would it show "MIKE"?

Comment: @ Littlefoot.  Also, did ``mike`` already have ``create table`` in your demo?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer and demonstrated what happens - based on questions you asked.